# JQuery: How to show current nested sub-menu and hide the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, nested

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
 $('li').not(this).each(function(){
  $(this).children('ul').addClass('hide');
 });
 $(this).children('ul').removeClass('hide');
});
```

Help me, please! I got several hours on this and I can't figure how to solve it. The code above it's for a horizontal multi-level menu. On click shows a sub-menu and hide all the other sub-menus, everything works fine until this point.

The problem comes when I need to open a sub-menu nested to a sub-menu. The code hide all the elements and show only de clicked sub-menu; hide all the elements including the parent of the sub-menu so the clicked sub-menu is not showed.

How to show and hide the nested sub-menu??? I hope somebody can help me and thanks a lot in advance. Here is the simplify menu HTML code, the classic nested unordered lists.

**Problem example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EddyRocket/b6t527qx/)**

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li>Item
  <ul class="sub-menu"><!--This works fine-->
   <li>Item
    <ul class="nested sub-menu"><!--Here is the problem-->
     <li>Item
      <ul class="nested sub-menu"><!--Here is the problem too-->
       <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Item
    <ul class="sub-menu"><!--This works fine-->
     <li>Item
      <ul class="nested sub-menu"><!--Here is the problem-->
       <li>Item
        <ul class="nested sub-menu"><!--Here is the problem too-->
         <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How are you binding event? Show that code

Comment: Sorry, the event is attached to <a class="show-menu">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop propagation. Without that all parents will fire the click event.

```js
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).children('ul').toggle();
  $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Item
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <!--This works fine-->
      <li>Item
        <ul class="nested sub-menu">
          <!--Here is the problem-->
          <li>Item
            <ul class="nested sub-menu">
              <!--Here is the problem too-->
              <li>Item</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
   <li>Item
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <!--This works fine-->
      <li>Item
        <ul class="nested sub-menu">
          <!--Here is the problem-->
          <li>Item
            <ul class="nested sub-menu">
              <!--Here is the problem too-->
              <li>Item</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Certainly this is a clean solution but the problem still. How to show the sub-menu in use and hide all the others? Thanks so much in advance! https://jsfiddle.net/EddyRocket/0nkvm1z9/

Comment: Perfect man! Thanks so much for the answer and this works because .siblings() affect all li's except for the clicked one, right? Thanks again, good vibes!

Answer (score 0):

I can read your html structure but i don't see how your css is, otherwise here is the sample i made for you i'm using BEM methodology .

[Code: example](http://jsfiddle.net/1nrjymyj/)

idea is simple add `display: none;` on nested item , on click item add class for example active and show nested item `display: block;`

on this example if you need more nested item simple add `ul` with class `primary-nav__subnav` inside `~__subnav`

```
<ul class="primary-nav__subnav">
   <a href="#" class="primary-nav__link">Nested 1</a>
      <ul class="primary-nav__subnav">
         <a href="#" class="primary-nav__link">Nested 2</a>            
      </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank so much for the answer! Yes, this solve the problem with the nested sub-menus but give me another problem, don't hide all the others sub-menus. I hoper you can help me! Thanks in advance! https://jsfiddle.net/EddyRocket/0nkvm1z9/

Comment: Hi, How can I make this horizontally, such that the child li items open from left to right and not from top to down? @ Thomas Theunen